# JQuery AJAX is not inserting HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

ajax working with the simple javascript but not with the jquery

Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function (){
   var url = 'data.json';

   $.getJSON(url, function(response){
    var htm = '<ul class="bulleted">';
    $.each(response, function(index, value){

        htm += '<li>';
        htm += value.name;
        htm += value.inoffice;
        htm += '</li>';

    });
    htm += '</ul>';
    $("container").html(htm);
   }); 
});
```

The problem is nothing is added in the container div.

Comment: Are you sure it's `container` and not `#container`?

Comment: Verify Adriano's idea by putting a console.log in your `each` to make sure you are actually getting values.

Comment: `$("container")` will return all container _tags_: `<container></container>`. If you're looking for an element with the container id, then it needs to be `$('#container')`

Comment: You really should supply a sample of your HTML so we can see what your elements are called.

Comment: Please add relevant HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Without being able to see your HTML, my guess would be that you've done your jQuery selector wrong when fetching your container.

- `$("container")` will select all `<container></container>` elements.
- `$("#containter")` will select `<div id="container"></div>` element.
- `$(".container")` will select all `<div class="container"></div>` elements.

Currently, you're using the first selector but that will only work if the element in your HTML is a `<container>`. If it's just a typo and you have an ID or a class, use one of the other selectors instead.